# How can I copy a hyper::Request in Rust?

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm making a proxy server using `tokio` and `hyper`. Depending on the request, there can be multiple proxy servers(can send request). I have the addresses of the servers to proxy as a vector and try to connect in turn.

For example, when a `GET /test HTTP/1.1` request is received, there are proxy server candidates named ["aaa.com", "bbb.com", "ccc.com"]. My server tries to connect in the order aaa -> bbb -> ccc and sends a proxy request to the server where the connection succeeds. If it cannot connect to all servers, a 500 error is returned.

The problem is that the same request must be sent until the connection to the server is successful, but if use `hyper`'s method, the request is consumed and a problem occurs in the next loop. But I couldn't find a way to copy `hyper::Request` (`clone`, etc.) How can I copy a `hyper::Request` in Rust?

```
fn proxy(
    mut req: Request<hyper::Body>,
) -> BoxFuture<'static, Response<hyper::Body>> {
    let route = req
        .extensions_mut()
        .remove::<RoutingInfo>()
        .expect("route not found.");

    let size = route.api_config.target_servers.len();

    Box::pin(async move {
        let mut index = 1;
        let resp = loop {    
           let target_server = schedule_server(&route);// get "aaa.com" or "bbb.com" or "ccc.com"
           let https = HttpsConnectorBuilder::new()
               .with_native_roots()
               .https_or_http()
               .enable_http1()
               .build();
           let client = Client::builder().build::<_, RawBody>(https);

           let destination = format!("{}{}", target_server, route.target_uri);
           *req.uri_mut() = destination.parse::<Uri>().unwrap();

           match client.request(req).await {
                Ok(resp) => {
                    break resp;
                },
                Err(_e) => {//TODO: only connection error
                    if index == size {
                        break Response::builder()
                            .status(StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                            .body(hyper::Body::empty())
                            .unwrap();
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            };
        };
        resp
    })
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `req`
  --> src/service/proxy.rs:83:14
   |
83 |             *req.uri_mut() = destination.parse::<Uri>().unwrap();
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
...
87 |            match client.request(req).await {
   |                                 --- value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

Comment: I don't think this is always possible as the request body could be a single-use value (a stream, for example) and so hyper doesn't implement such an API. Maybe consider using `reqwest`; its `Request` type has a [`try_clone`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Request.html#method.try_clone) method that will fail at runtime if the body is a single-use value.